# IntelliSense in a browser

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, intellisense

I need to implement a functionality very similar to IntelliSense in VS: code autocompletion, etc. But in a web page, is there any framework out there to achieve so? What would be the best approach for it?

Comment: Questions asking for a library tool framework etc belong to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/